# User reputation history sort bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, sorting

When looking at my reputation history, I noticed that when I sort by time, it only sorts the days that are expanded by default (today, yesterday, and 2 days ago) and that when I expand something older it is still sorted by post.

Here is a screenshot of the behavior (with today and 2 days ago collapsed because they get in the way):

[image]

Comment: Love the freehand lines ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug was that the controller didn't handle the sort parameter in the ajax request of the expander arrow, and used the sorting rules for the post tab, which sorts by reputation.

Fixed in next build that rolls out. Watch for version numbers 2013.12.30.1811 on sites and 2013.12.30.1270.

Comment: Congrats for sharing some dirty technical details with us! ;-)

Comment: http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/chatty-chatty

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce this.

It would seem that today, yesterday, and 2 days ago are sorted by time.

Anything past that is sorted by reputation. I am not sure if this is by design or a bug though.

Note also that the only reputation lists expanded when you select time are today, yesterday, and 2 days ago.